# How to remove the content from a div but keep a loading image?

Tags: jquery

How exactly do you remove you load to a div but keep the loading image for the next time? I'm using the empty() function, which removes everything from the div--including the loading image.

Comment: You need to show your code because you can create loading with 1000 ways of code.

Comment: Don't put the loading image in the div that you're emptying.

Comment: @Dvir it's literally just a code that says $('this').click(function(){ $(this).empty(); });

Comment: @Barmar... i feel like a genius now... thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could put it into a div which you will hide/show when you add/remove content but that won't really work with using `empty()` before inserting content. The way I do it is to store the code for the image in a variable and do the same thing as with your content e.g. `empty() -> html(loadingCode) -> (ready -> [empty() -> html(content)])`

Answer (score 0):

assuming a div called `yourDiv` containing a loading image (or loading image container) of class `loadingImage`

```
var loader=$('#yourdiv .loadingImage');
$('#yourdiv').empty().append(loader);
```

Answer (score 0):

Because there is no code I'll give you the quicker way in my opinion.

```
function appendLoading(divname) {
   var loading = "<img src='' class='loading' />";
   $(divname).append(loading);
}
function removeLoading(divname) {
   $(divname).find(".loading").remove();
}
```

see wroking example for you:
[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5jKBm/)